# Postgresql: same select works in psql but do not work when run as command

Tags: postgresql

On `PostgreSQL 11.13 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44), 64-bit`,
when I run

```
select * from pg_stat_activity where datname = 'db_name';
```

while connected directly to the database it works.

But, when I run it as:

```sh
psql -h <address> -U postgres -d postgres -c 'select * from pg_stat_activity where datname = 'db_name';'
```

it returns:

```
ERROR:  column "db_name" does not exist<br />
LINE 1: select * from pg_stat_activity where datname = "db_name"
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use single quotes within single quotes, so try this:

```sh
psql -c "select \* from pg_stat_activity where datname = 'db_name'"
```

The `*` must be escaped with a backslash in double quotes.

Comment: Thanks, looks I needed only double quotes, no need to escape * , so, it worked like: psql -c "select * from pg_stat_activity where datname = 'db_name'"